# why my HTTP Request not working in Android OS 4.3 and below versions?

Tags: android, web-services, http

I have an Android app, and it get the response from both webservices.The webservices written in PHP.
    Webservices Hosted in Live server and my request will be HTTP and HTTPS.Below the code working good in 
    Android 5.0,6.0,7.0, and i tested with 4.4.2 also its working nice. 
    but when i try to run my app in Android 4.3 my app will be crashed .

what i have tried ,

```
try{

   String url = dRequestParam.getURL();
   HttpEntity httpEntity;
   HttpResponse httpResponse;
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient;

   if(url.startsWith("http://")){
    //http client
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpEntity = null;
    httpResponse = null;

   }else{

    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
    SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);

    int AdFetchTimeout=Integer.parseInt(AdView.getFetchTimeout());
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, AdFetchTimeout);
    httpEntity = null;
    httpResponse = null;
   }
            //checking http request method type
            if(method == POST){
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
                //adding post params
                if(params != null){
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            }else if(method == GET){
                //appending params to url
                params = AdRequestParam.getURL_PARAMS();

                if(params != null){
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                // SET HEADERS PARAMETERS

                hParams = AdRequestParam.getHEADER_PARAMS();

                for (NameValuePair nvp : hParams) {
                    String name = nvp.getName();
                    String value = nvp.getValue();
                    Cdlog.d(Cdlog.httpReqLogTag,name+"=>"+value);
                    httpGet.setHeader(name,value);
                }
                Long startTime = null;
                try {         
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                    Cdlog.d(Cdlog.httpReqLogTag,url);
                    Cdlog.setLastRequest(url);

                    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Cdlog.d(Cdlog.httpResLogTag,response);
                    Cdlog.setLastResponse(response);
                  }
                  catch(SocketTimeoutException se) {
                    Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    se.printStackTrace();
                  }          
                  catch(ConnectTimeoutException cte) {
                    Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                  response="{\"ad_available\":\"5\",\"ad_tag\":\"<div></div>\"}";
                    cte.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  catch (ClientProtocolException e) {            
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  catch (IOException e) {
                    Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                //DAC125 Timeout Mechanism

            }


        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            Log.d("Unsupported Encoding Exception",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            Log.d("Client Protocol Exception",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("IO Exception",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(SecurityException e){
            Log.d("Security Exception",e.getMessage());
            //response = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

        return response;
    }
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'http' not registered.

63.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6479/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415a1700)

64.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)

65.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:160)

66.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)

67.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at com.vrtcal.openfalls.adserver.AdFetcher$RequestHandler.handleMessage(AdFetcher.java:230)

68.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

69.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

70.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

71.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

72.   01-18 10:49:22.552 6417-6417/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

Comment: Please make use of retrofit or volley. It's on GitHub. Please.

Comment: Okay client Requested to me no need 3rd parties thats the problem now

Comment: Starting from API 23 apache client in fact is 3rd party lib on android ... also you didn't register http only https

Comment: Coder_07, explain to the client how important some 3rd party libraries are. HttpClient shouldn't be used in place of other better libraries. HttpURLConnection is even better if you still want to stick to the 'no 3rd party library' rule of your client

Comment: sure i will explain @SalaudeenAbdulrahman

Comment: @Selvin did you mean in Android 4.3 -- API 18 only support HTTPS ???it does not support HTTP????

Comment: when i test with 4.3.2 its working